# How to connect to bluetooth device quicker after system startup

Tags: startup, bluetooth, pop-os

When I turn on my PC, it takes a while (30 to 60 seconds I would guess) between arriving at the login screen and my bluetooth keyboard being connected. Is there a way to speed this up?

I don't think the keyboard is the problem, since it connects a lot quicker to my chromebook from work.

I'm on pop_os 22.04 and I also have edited `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` to include:

```
FastConnectable = true
AutoEnable=true
```